# Referencing Charts By Name Only in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I have been searching for hours to try to find the answer to this question, but to no avail, so I'm hoping I can find the answer here.

I want to create a variable that refers to a pre-existing chart in PowerPoint so I can start automating its data.  I want to refer to the chart by its name to make things very easy, but no matter what I do I cannot seem to give PPT a satisfactory Chart address.

I have tried almost every possible variation of the below, but without success:

```
Dim chrtPP As PowerPoint.Chart

Set chrtPP = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Charts("Chart3")
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Powerpoint doesn't have a Charts collection the way Excel does; it has Shapes, and a Shape might contain a Chart (or in the case of pasted content from Excel, BE a chart).  In your situation ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.("Chart3") should do it (ie, remove the .Charts part)

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the shape by name (a 'Shape" in PowerPoint is actually any object that is on a slide and can be a simple shape, textbox, table, chart, group, media clip etc.). If you're on PowerPoint 2010 and higher, press Alt+F10 to open the selection pane to find the name of the selected chart object. It may be a standard chart object or a chart within a placeholder object. You can then reference the chart as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartStuff()
  Dim oShp As Shape
  Dim oCht As Chart

  Set oShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 3")
  If oShp.HasChart Then
    Set oCht = oShp.Chart
  End If

  ' Do stuff with your chart
  If oCht.HasTitle Then Debug.Print oCht.ChartTitle.Text

  ' Clean up
  Set oShp = Nothing
  Set oCht = Nothing
End Sub
```

The key in programming PowerPoint is to ignore the object name in the Object Model for 'Shape' as it's very misleading!